# mac os keylistener not working

Tags: java, macos, swing, keylistener

I am facing a problem with my java keylistner. I can´t set it to work. 
I have tried several ways, but my windows doesn´t seem to get focus.

The code is as it follows (partial).

```
public class TicTacTowerShooter extends JPanel implements Runnable,KeyListener {
/**
 * 
 */
int queenArrayIndex = 0;
TexturePaint tp;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private  BufferedImage biCastle = new BufferedImage(1024, 1024, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
private  BufferedImage biChar = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Thread thread;
int posCharX = this.getWidth()/2;
int posCharY;

Shape s;


URL url;
Snakes snakes = new Snakes();


public TicTacTowerShooter(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024,1024)); 
    setBackground(Color.blue);
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    try{                
        url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Images/castle.jpg");                 
        biCastle = ImageIO.read(url);
        url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Images/shooter.png");
        biChar = ImageIO.read(url);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);

}
```

Then in the keyListener mothods i just have (in all of them to test) a single output saying it´s working.

I would apreciate your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Try `requestFocusInWindow();`

Comment: Also perhaps try not starting the thread until you have done everything you need to with the window.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can only request focus on a visible component on a visible GUI. Therefore you can't request focus in the constructor.
2. You should NOT be using a KeyListener anyway. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). When using key bindings the component does not (always) need to have focus to respond to the key binding.

Comment: @user3143003, the slowness has nothing to do with key bindings.